# showing all values present for a field(a field can have multiple values) in table

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench, pentaho, kettle

I have a table A which looks like:

```
number    value
 1           A
 1           B
 2           C
```

And I have a csv file which contains number as one of the columns. When I do a (pentaho)database lookup on this table with number from that csv file i get an output like:

```
number     value
  1         A
  2         C
```

Is there any other way in ETL where the output must be like:

```
 number    value
  1          A
  1          B
  2          C
```

Comment: how are you doing pentaho database lookup? You output result set ideally conveys that a GROUP BY is happening when you are doing the lookup. If you can change that then all the records will be selected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Database Value Lookup` step is designed to return at most 1 row for any given input value. If you want to get all rows for a key you can use a `Database Join` step, or read all rows from the table and the csv file, sort them, and flow them through a `Merge Join` step.

These correspond roughly to a nested lookup join and a sort merge join respectively. You would choose between them in the same way a query optimizer would. Basically the rule of thumb is if the number of rows in the table and the csv are roughly the same, the `Merge Join` will be faster, otherwise use the `Database Join` step. This is of course a 'rule of thumb', and will not suit every situation. Experimentation is encouraged if performance is critical.